# Creating a non-public DNS alias for a database in Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

Tags: domain-name-system, mysql, google-cloud-platform, database, internal-dns

I am currently working on setting up a database in Google Cloud Platform (GCP), and I would like to create a non-public DNS alias for it. The purpose of this alias is to provide a more user-friendly name for accessing the database internally within my GCP project, without exposing the actual database endpoint or IP address.

I have explored various options within GCP, but I haven't found a straightforward way to achieve this. My goal is to have a custom DNS alias that points to the database instance, allowing other resources within the project to connect to the database using this alias.

I appreciate any insights or suggestions.

I have tried searching for a solution in the "VPC settings" (Virtual Private Cloud) within the Google Cloud Console. I hoped to find a configuration or option that would allow me to create a DNS alias for my database instance. Additionally, I searched through the GCP documentation, including the official Cloud SQL documentation, to find any guidance or recommended approach for creating a non-public DNS alias.

I was expecting to find a straightforward method or a built-in functionality within GCP, specifically in the Cloud SQL service, that would enable me to create a non-public DNS alias for my database. Ideally, I was hoping to discover step-by-step instructions or documentation explaining the process, best practices, and any potential limitations or considerations associated with this approach

Comment: Look into Google Cloud DNS Private Zones. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/introducing-private-dns-zones-resolve-to-keep-internal-networks-concealed